# login with AD user when "winbind use default domain" not set

Tags: ssh, samba4

I have a Samba4 domain controller and have added a Ubuntu 16.04 member server to the domain. I'm using samba+winbind for this and everything appears to work. The idmap backend is setup using "ad". Here is the smb.conf for reference.

```
[global]
        workgroup = name
        realm = NAME.DOMAIN.COM
        netbios name = app02
        security = ADS
        log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
        log level = 1

        # Default idmap config for local BUILTIN accounts and groups
        idmap config * : backend = tdb
        idmap config * : range = 3000-7999

        # idmap config for the NAME domain
        idmap config NAME:backend = ad
        idmap config NAME:schema_mode = rfc2307
        idmap config NAME:range = 10000-999999

        # Template settings for login shell and home directory
        winbind nss info = template
        template shell = /bin/bash
        template homedir = /home/%U
        winbind use default domain = yes
```

The issue I'm having is related to authenticating (SSH) when I do NOT set `winbind use default domain = yes` in smb.conf.

When you set this equal to yes the various commands like `wbinfo -u`, `wbinfo -g`, `getent passwd UserName` will return an account WITHOUT the domain name. If you don't set this you get results like `Domain\UserName` and `Domain\Domain Users`. The reason you might not want to set this is because it would limit your logins to a single domain.

However, when I remove this setting from smb.conf I can no longer login. I suspect it is a formatting issue when trying to provide domain\username at the SSH login. I've tried domain\username, domain+username, username, and username@domain. All have failed.

Does anyone know how to get SSH logins working for these AD users when `winbind use default domain` is not set?

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the problem

I was removing the `winbind use default domain` setting in `smb.conf` and then running `sudo smbcontrol all reload-config`. I figured this would be enough to set everything straight, but it wasn't.

For whatever reason winbind wasn't updating. I need to stop the service, clear the cache, and restart.

```
service winbind stop
net cache flush
service winbind start
```

Strange enough, once I did this the problem hasn't resurfaced. Now I can change the `winbind use default domain` setting and/or the `winbind separator`, run `sudo smbcontrol all reload-config`, and the login credentials change and work.